# Am getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Tags: php

Am getting unexpected end of file error on line 340 or so. I just can't figure out the solution. Someone please help. I tried Cheking some solutions online. Mostly I was told to space php tags from brackets, I tried that but still

```
<?php
/*!
 * Theme Name: xx
 * Theme URI: http://www.example.com
 * Version: 1.0
 * Description: 
 * Author: JM Team - example.com
 * Author URI: http://www.example.com
 * 
 * Powered by Magento
 * Licensed under the Apache License v2.0
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 * 
 */
$baseconfig =  Mage::helper("jmtheme")->getactiveprofile();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
<!--[if IE]>
<html class="ie" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="ie8" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>
<html class="ie9" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 10]>
<html class="ie10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
<![endif]-->
<head>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>
<body id="bd" class="<?php echo $this->getBodyClass();?> <?php echo 'skin-'.Mage::helper("jmbasetheme")->getprofile(); ?>">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
<div id="jm-wrapper">
    <!-- BEGIN: HEADER -->
    <div id="jm-header" class="wrap clearfix">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
    </div>
    <!-- END: HEADER -->
    <?php if($baseconfig["urlfacebook"] || $baseconfig["urltwitter"] || $baseconfig["urlgoogleplus"] || $baseconfig["urlpinterest"] || $baseconfig["urltumblr"] || $baseconfig["urlskype"]): ?>
        <div class="sidebar-socials">
            <?php if($baseconfig["urlfacebook"]): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $baseconfig["urlfacebook"]; ?>" class="fa fa-facebook facebook"></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if($baseconfig["urltwitter"]): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $baseconfig["urltwitter"]; ?>" class="fa fa-twitter twitter"></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if($baseconfig["urlgoogleplus"]): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $baseconfig["urlgoogleplus"]; ?>" class="fa fa-google-plus google-plus"></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if($baseconfig["urlpinterest"]): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $baseconfig["urlpinterest"]; ?>" class="fa fa-pinterest pinterest"></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if($baseconfig["urltumblr"]): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $baseconfig["urltumblr"]; ?>" class="fa fa-tumblr tumblr"></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if($baseconfig["urlskype"]): ?>
            <a href="skype:<?php echo $baseconfig["urlskype"]; ?>?call" class="fa fa-skype skype"></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    <!-- BEGIN: toolbar -->
    <div id="jm-head" class="wrap clearfix">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('jmtoolbar') ?>
    </div>
    <!-- END: toolbar -->
    <?php if ($this->getChildHtml('tops1')) : ?>
    <!-- TOP SPOTLIGHT -->
    <div id="jm-tops1" class="jm-position wrap clearfix">
        <div class="main col1-set">
            <div class="inner clearfix">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('tops1') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- //TOP SPOTLIGHT -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($this->getChildHtml('tops2')) : ?>
    <!-- //TOP SPOTLIGHT 2 -->
    <div id="jm-tops2" class="jm-position wrap clearfix">
        <div class="main col3-set">
            <div class="inner clearfix">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('tops2') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- //TOP SPOTLIGHT 2 -->  
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($this->getChildHtml('tops3')) : ?>
    <!-- //TOP SPOTLIGHT 3 -->
    <div id="jm-tops3" class="jm-position wrap clearfix">
        <div class="main col1-set">
            <div class="inner">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('tops3') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- //TOP SPOTLIGHT 3 -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($this->getChildHtml('tops4')) : ?>
    <!-- //TOP SPOTLIGHT 4 -->
    <div id="jm-tops4" class="jm-position wrap clearfix">
        <div class="main col1-set">
            <div class="inner">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('tops4') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- //TOP SPOTLIGHT 4 -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($this->getChildHtml('tops5')) : ?>
    <!-- //TOP SPOTLIGHT 5 -->
    <div id="jm-tops5" class="jm-position wrap clearfix">
        <div class="main col1-set">
            <div class="inner">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('tops5') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- //TOP SPOTLIGHT 5 -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($this->getChildHtml('tops6')) : ?>
    <!-- //TOP SPOTLIGHT 6 -->
    <div id="jm-tops6" class="jm-position wrap clearfix">
        <div class="main col1-set">
            <div class="inner">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('tops6') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- //TOP SPOTLIGHT 6 -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($this->getChildHtml('tops7')) : ?>
    <!-- //TOP SPOTLIGHT 7 -->
    <div id="jm-tops7" class="jm-position wrap clearfix">
        <div class="main col1-set">
            <div class="inner">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('tops7') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- //TOP SPOTLIGHT 7 -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($this->getChildHtml('tops8')) : ?>
    <!-- //TOP SPOTLIGHT 8 -->
    <div id="jm-tops8" class="jm-position wrap clearfix">
        <div class="main col1-set">
            <div class="inner">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('tops8') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- //TOP SPOTLIGHT 8 -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($this->getChildHtml('tops9')) : ?>
    <!-- //TOP SPOTLIGHT 9 -->
    <div id="jm-tops9" class="jm-position wrap clearfix">
        <div class="main col1-set">
            <div class="inner">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('tops9') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- //TOP SPOTLIGHT 9 -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($this->getChildHtml('tops10')) : ?>
    <!-- //TOP SPOTLIGHT 10 -->
    <div id="jm-tops10" class="jm-position wrap clearfix">
        <div class="main col1-set">
            <div class="inner">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('tops10') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- //TOP SPOTLIGHT 10 -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($this->getChildHtml('tops11')) : ?>
    <!-- //TOP SPOTLIGHT 11 -->
    <div id="jm-tops11" class="jm-position wrap clearfix">
        <div class="main col1-set">
            <div class="inner">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('tops11') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- //TOP SPOTLIGHT 11 -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($this->getChildHtml('tops12')) : ?>
    <!-- //TOP SPOTLIGHT 12 -->
    <div id="jm-tops12" class="jm-position wrap clearfix">
        <div class="main col1-set">
            <div class="inner">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('tops12') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- //TOP SPOTLIGHT 12 -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($this->getChildHtml('mass-top')) : ?>
    <!-- //TOP MASS -->
    <div id="jm-mass-top" class="jm-mass-top wrap clearfix">
        <div class="main col1-set">
            <div class="inner clearfix">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('mass-top') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- //TOP MASS -->
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs')) : ?>
    <!-- breadcrums -->
    <div id="jm-breadcrumbs" class="wrap clearfix">
        <div class="main clearfix">
            <div class="inner clearfix">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
    <!-- // breadcrums -->
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if($this->getChildHtml('global_messages') || $this->getChildHtml('messages')) :?>
    <div id="jm-messages" class="wrap clearfix">
        <div class="main clearfix">
            <div class="inner clearfix">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('messages') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <!-- BEGIN: MAIN CONTAINER -->
    <div id="jm-container" class="jm-col2-left-layout <?php if(!$this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs')) { echo "not-breadcrumbs"; } ?> wrap clearfix">
        <div class="main clearfix">
            <div id="jm-mainbody" class="clearfix">
                <!-- BEGIN: CONTENT -->
                <div id="jm-main">
                    <div class="inner clearfix">
                        <div id="jm-current-content" class="clearfix">
                            <!-- //TOP SPOTLIGHT 3 -->
                            <?php if ($this->getChildHtml('mass-top')) : ?>
                            <div id="jm-mass-top" class="jm-mass-top clearfix">
                                <div class="col1-set">
                                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('mass-top') ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <!-- //TOP SPOTLIGHT 3 -->
                            <!-- MASS Head -->
                            <?php if ($this->getChildHtml('mass-head')) : ?>
                            <div id="jm-mass-head" class="jm-mass-head">
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('mass-head') ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <!-- primary content -->
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                            <!-- // primary content -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- END: CONTENT -->
                <!-- BEGIN: COLUMN 1 -->
                <div id="jm-col1" class="col-left sidebar">
                    <div class="inner clearfix">
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- END: COLUMN 1 -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END: MAIN CONTAINER -->
    <?php if ($this->getChildHtml('mass-bottom')) : ?>
    <!-- //BOTTOM SPOTLIGHT -->
    <div id="jm-mass-bottom" class="jm-mass-bottom wrap clearfix">
        <div class="main col3-set">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('mass-bottom') ?>        
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- //BOTTOM SPOTLIGHT -->
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($this->getChildHtml('bots1')) : ?>
    <!-- BOTTOM SPOTLIGHT -->
    <div id="jm-bots1" class="wrap clearfix">
        <div class="main col2-set clearfix">
            <div class="inner clearfix">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bots1') ?>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- //BOTTOM SPOTLIGHT -->
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($this->getChildHtml('bots2')) : ?>
    <!-- BOTTOM SPOTLIGHT -->
    <div id="jm-bots2" class="wrap clearfix">
        <div class="main col1-set clearfix">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bots2') ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- //BOTTOM SPOTLIGHT -->
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($this->getChildHtml('bots3')) : ?>
    <!-- BOTTOM SPOTLIGHT -->
    <div id="jm-bots3" class="wrap clearfix">
        <div class="main col1-set clearfix">
            <div class="inner clearfix">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bots3') ?>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- //BOTTOM SPOTLIGHT -->
    <?php endif; ?>
    <!-- BEGIN: FOOTER -->
    <div id="jm-footer" class="wrap clearfix">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="inner clearfix">
                <div class="inner2 clearfix">
                  <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END: FOOTER -->
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: You don't have an endif for both `<?php if($baseconfig["urlfacebook"] ||...` and `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?>`

Comment: @Fred-ii- wow, that are some good eagle eyes! :D Didn't spot that one

Comment: @Rizier123 I wonder if the OP or anyone else actually "counted" them ;-) answer given, lookah dat.

Comment: @haf99 great and you're welcome. Shall I convert my comment toan  answer then?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I would say yes, since this is how SO rolls. Otherwise this question is laying on the Stack forever.

Comment: @haf99 If you didn't already saw it you can take a tour here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and see how this site works! (Welcome on SO)

Comment: @Rizier123 Yep, I'd say so. *Done*

Answer (score 2):

*Posting my comment to an answer:*

You don't have an `endif` for both `<?php if($baseconfig["urlfacebook"] ||...`
and `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?>`

You have 29 `if` conditions and 27 `endif`'s

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you forgot to close an if condition so it should look like this:

```
<?php if($baseconfig["urlfacebook"] || $baseconfig["urltwitter"] || $baseconfig["urlgoogleplus"] || $baseconfig["urlpinterest"] || $baseconfig["urltumblr"] || $baseconfig["urlskype"]): ?>
    <div class="sidebar-socials">
        <?php if($baseconfig["urlfacebook"]): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $baseconfig["urlfacebook"]; ?>" class="fa fa-facebook facebook"></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($baseconfig["urltwitter"]): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $baseconfig["urltwitter"]; ?>" class="fa fa-twitter twitter"></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($baseconfig["urlgoogleplus"]): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $baseconfig["urlgoogleplus"]; ?>" class="fa fa-google-plus google-plus"></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($baseconfig["urlpinterest"]): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $baseconfig["urlpinterest"]; ?>" class="fa fa-pinterest pinterest"></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($baseconfig["urltumblr"]): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $baseconfig["urltumblr"]; ?>" class="fa fa-tumblr tumblr"></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($baseconfig["urlskype"]): ?>
        <a href="skype:<?php echo $baseconfig["urlskype"]; ?>?call" class="fa fa-skype skype"></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```